# Dynamic or Static column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have some tables in databases. The table contains more than 150 columns for some custom field operations which may/may not be used by all. Instead of creating static 150 unused column fields, it can be created dynamically using `add column`.

Can somebody justify, which one is better? When to use dynamic, when static and why?

Comment: Adding columns on a large table will take time and the whole table must be locked during this operation. Also, 150 columns feels like an anti-pattern may be at work here.

Comment: We are using LHM to take care of locking problem. Is there any other way to create column dynamically instead of static? Because most of the fields are null( Except some 5 columns, all other columns are empty). Will dynamic operation reduces space and time complexity?

Comment: It is a rails application, so we using LHM ( Large hadron migration developed by Soundcloud) to take care of locking problem during migration.

Comment: Let me put it differently, why do you need so many columns? Can't you normalise the database a bit more?

Comment: I'm in need of some custom fields for a form. customers might use those fields to create more customised forms.

Comment: Even If I add dynamically, if a customer added all some 5-6 fields, then empty 5-6 columns would be created for all the customers with the value null.. If I normalise and split the table in two, it might end-up as wrong pattern in long run. Is there is any other solution to solve this problems ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for below normalization for maintaining custom fields, I have used in multiple web/window application successfully.

**FormMasterTable**

```
FormId, Name: this will be identifier and will be passed from Form to DB query to identify itself
```

**datatypeMaster Table**

```
datatypeId, datatypeName
```

The abobe will define all custom fields you are going to support i.e. customer can create to customize a form.

**Table for Form-Customer-CustomFieldMapping** say **Custom Field Master Table** for managing column definition and mapping with customer.

```
customerId, FormName/FormId,    FieldName,  customFieldId,  datatypeId(FK:datatypeMaster), length ....
```

Next step is to create all tables to store all datatypes defined in datatypeMaster table i.e. one table for each datatype, some of the examples I can think of....

**Custom field detail table for numeric say CustomNumberFields**

```
customFieldId FieldValue(numeric(max))
```

**Custom field detail table for string say CustomTextFields**

```
customFieldId FieldValue(varchar(max))
```

**Custom field detail table for Dates say CustomDateFields**

```
customFieldId FieldValue(datetime)
```

and so on....

Now you can use all in one query  with Inner Join to get all custom columns of a customer.

Sample Query to get customfields fields

```
select MP.FieldName, CFN.FieldValue from Form-Customer-CustomFieldMapping MP
JOIN CustomNumberFields CFN on MP.CustomFieldId and CFN.CustomFieldId where formId=<<paramformId>> and customerId=<<paramcustomerId>>                   
UNION 
    select MP.FieldName, CFN.FieldValue from  Form-Customer-CustomFieldMapping MP                           
JOIN CustomTextFields CFN on MP.CustomFieldId and CFN.CustomFieldId where formId=<<paramformId>>                    and customerId=<<paramcustomerId>>  

UNION

select MP.FieldName, CFN.FieldValue from Form-Customer-CustomFieldMapping MP 
JOIN CustomDateFields CFN on MP.CustomFieldId and CFN.CustomFieldId where formId=<<paramformId>>    and     customerId=<<paramcustomerId>>
```

Comment: Assume I have millions/billions of customers for my application.. Case 1 : The above normalised method will require lot of inner joins - time complexity over long run. Case 2: without normalising , having all columns in the single table - may/may not have null values in most of the field - space complexity.  So both cases have pros and cons.. It depends upon the requirement.. I guess case 2 is better..

Comment: As per my DB design you only need four tables to get all custom fields of a form and for a customer, refer my updated answer